# how to open mysql shell

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, docker, ubuntu-16.04

```
sudo docker run -i -t f92f0896ed95 /bin/bash

[Entrypoint] MySQL Docker Image 5.7.21-1.1.3
bash-4.2# mysql

ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)

bash-4.2#
```

Comment: Mentioned here too:

https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/360

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing MySQL in Docker fails with error message "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23234379/installing-mysql-in-docker-fails-with-error-message-cant-connect-to-local-mysq)

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure `~/.my.cnf` with your credentials, then `mysql` shell can be opened directly.

Example of content :

```
[client]
user=dba
password=foobar
# depends of what is configured, can be a hostname or 127.0.0.1, it's matter :
host=localhost
```

Or if you can't configure the image, do this :

```
mysql -h localhost -p
```

Then you will be prompted to enter the password

Comment: i am using docker...so what is can type after bash-4.2# for entering into mysql shell

Answer (score 0):

First run your image standard and then connect to the running image with:

```
docker exec -it f92f0896ed95 /bin/sh
```

Comment: Agreed, I would make sure the container starts up without errors. Then you can connect to it as above, or use `mysql` instead of `/bin/sh` to connect to the mysql client directly via the exec command -- adding whatever params you need (host, username, etc). Note that "localhost" in a Unix-type environment will try to use the socket by default, so try 127.0.0.1 if "localhost" doesn't work -- but the socket _should_ work.