# Docker Mysql Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket

Tags: docker

I'm using below command to run the mysql docker container.

```
docker container run -it --name mysql-test -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret mysql bash
```

Then I tried to connect to mysql inside docker container using below command.

```
mysql -uroot -psecret
```

It gives me below error.

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

If I do below then sometimes it works but not all time.

```
touch /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

Then I tried to run the container in detach mode but it also gave me the same error.

```
docker container run -d -p 3306:3306 --name mysql-test -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret mysql
docker exec -it mysql-test bash
mysql -uroot -p
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing MySQL in Docker fails with error message "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23234379/installing-mysql-in-docker-fails-with-error-message-cant-connect-to-local-mysq)

Comment: @paulsm4 i'm not connecting remotely. i'm connecting with same container.

Comment: Read ... the ... responses.  *All* the responses.

Comment: Are you trying to connect mysql installed on local from inside the docker? If so, have you used -v /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock:/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock for mounting volumes?

Comment: @deosha i'm connecting to the mysql container's bash.

Answer (score 4):

If you happen to get “Can’t connect to local MySQL server through socket ‘/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock’ (2)” errors in logging in to mysql-server while working on docker containers:

check the path of socket file in /etc/mysql/my.cnf

check if mysqld.sock and mysqld.pid file is present in /var/run/mysqld/ directory or not.

If not, create these files as:

```
touch /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
touch /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
chown -R mysql:mysql /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
chown -R mysql:mysql /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
chmod -R 644 /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

Now restart the mysql-server as:

```
service mysql-server restart
```

Now, trying logging again in to mysql-server.

Answer (score 2):

This [Connect to mysql in a docker container from the host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33001750/connect-to-mysql-in-a-docker-container-from-the-host) may help.

1. mysql command try to connect via mysqld.sock, but your mysql server are running inside a container, so no .sock file here. You can try to mount it to the host.
2. you touch a .sock file, ofcourse it don't make any thing work, maybe you would like to understand what is a sock file :)

Comment: I'm not connecting form the host. i'm connecting from the container.

Comment: I am sorry about that. Can you give ouput of `docker container logs mysql-test`

Comment: I forgot to check the logs and lost it. i try to do it again